How are different creature types affected by a Cube of Force?
Having just come into possession of a Cube of Force, I'd appreciate guidance on how each creature type is restricted by the barrier.
Here is the key text in 5e describing Cube of Force options and effects (Dungeon Master's Guide P. 160):

Face 1: Gases, wind, and fog can't pass through the barrier.
Face 2: Nonliving matter can't pass through the barrier. Walls, floors, and ceilings can pass through at your discretion.
Face 3: Living matter can't pass through the barrier.
Face 4: Spell effects can't pass through the barrier.
Face 5: Nothing can pass through the barrier. Walls, floors, and ceilings can pass through at your discretion.
Face 6: The barrier deactivates.

And here is the list of creature types appearing in Monsters of the Multiverse on Page 6:

Aberration, Beast, Celestial, Construct, Dragon, Elemental, Fey,
Fiend, Giant, Humanoid, Monstrosity, Ooze, Plant, Undead.

While I would tend to consider all creatures other than "Undead" and perhaps "Constructs" as "Living Matter", I would like to validate this assumption with the community. Thus, my question is which specific creature types (if any) will be blocked by Face 2 (Nonliving matter) and Face 3 (Living matter).

We’ve closed this as a duplicate, I think the linked question should answer this, even though it’s about a different magic item.
